# What can I do to the function of an archimedian spiral to make the sprial eccentric?

Tags: functions, circular-motion

I know the function of an archimedian spiral is `r=theta`. Is there a way to "squish" the spiral to make it thinner or taller? I'm trying to code something that requires an eccentric spiral.

Comment: Try $r=c\theta$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Squishing is easy in cartesian coordinates (scale one or the other of $x$ or $y$). Why not try converting your spiral to cartesian, squish it (anisotropic scaling), then convert back to polar?

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. I did something like ```y = x tan (radical of (10x^2 + y^2))```